# How to use the Netbeans Profiler programmatically?

Tags: java, api, netbeans, profiler

I want to be able to do some profiling to some app using the Netbeans Profiler API. I'm not interested in using Visual VM , but rather in programmatically collecting data from the application[let's say CPU usage, and method execution times]. For instance, using CPU usage and hot methods. How to get that data and print it on console for instance?

Comment: I think you can build your custom profiler with help of NetBeans source code.
Here is the link [src code for NetBeans profiler](https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans) I hope this may work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was from Jiri Sedlacek -  one of the VisualVM develpers:

> There's nothing like 'Netbeans
>   Profiler API', the profiler doesn't
>   have any API for public usage. Neither
>   VisualVM nor the NetBeans Profiler
>   will help you with this

So that's it folks!

Answer (score 1):

JRockit Mission Control have according to [new and noteworthy](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jrockit/missioncontrol/new_and_noteworthy/3.1.0/index.html) for the 3.1 release a public API that be used to subscribe to JMX-data and to establish connections to local/remote servers. See at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The only problem remains that JRockit Mission Control only works well with Oracle's JVM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of providing the updated information: Netbeans is code is public under https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans

Under the module profiler, the code can be used for getting required information programmatically.